# Regex to limit validate hex values from 0000 to 7F7F

Tags: java, regex, validation, hex

In the code below I'm validating that a string is a valid hex
Is there a way to validate that a hex value is limited to a value between 0000 and 7F7F?

```
value.matches("[0-9a-fA-F]+")
```

Comment: Regex can't do math. Why you would want to to do this rather than simply parsing and checking the integer range is completely beyond me.

Comment: That character class happens to also exist as `\p{XDigit}`

Comment: Is regex the only option (eg that's the API), or is arbitrary code OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know the value is a valid hex number, you can use some [simple regex tricks for checking if a number is in a range](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html). If you don't plan on parsing the number, this is a more efficient option.

```
value.matches("(?i)[0-6]...|7[0-9A-E]..|7F[0-7].");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just convert the value to an int and use regular `<` and `>` operators:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int LOW = 0x0000;
        final int HIGH = 0x7F7F;
        String sample1 = "A1A1";
        String sample2 = "2ABC";

        int hex1 = Integer.decode("0x"+sample1);
        System.out.println(LOW < hex1 && hex1 < HIGH);
        int hex2 = Integer.decode("0x"+sample2);
        System.out.println(LOW < hex2 && hex2 < HIGH);
    }
}
```

Output:

> false
>   true